# F# Get database table data

Tags: sql, f#

I'm trying to get data from an Azure SQL Server. I've Been able to get the data through this method:

```
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    let serviceType = db.table
    serviceType
```

I then go on to do some type casting where I get the actual data. But as my program has progressed I need a new way of getting the data.

I'm able to get a list of column names with this piece of code:

```
 let columnList = (new SqlCommandProvider<"select * from Information_schema.Columns where table_name = @tableName",connectionString).Execute(tableName)
```

I'm wondering if there's a similar way to get the data.

I've tried:

```
let data = (new SqlCommandProvider<"select * from @tableName",connectionstring).Execute(tableName)
```

But I get this error: "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."

Comment: the second example should help: http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/

Comment: The probability provider?

Comment: no, the SqlCommandProvider

Comment: I've made a number of attempts at it but I still end up with either that line I've already tried, or an error stating the table name input variable is not defined.

Comment: Maybe that could be a different Q, on how to parametrize (if possible) the table name in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this.

```
let GetData (tableName : string) =
    let cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    cn.Open()
    let sQL = "select * from [" + tableName + "]"
    let db = new SqlCommand(sQL, cn)
    db.ExecuteReader()
```

From here you can access your data. So assign db.ExecuteReader() to a variable then...

```
let dataSource = db.ExecuteReader()
let mutable tableData = List.empty

while dataSource.Read() do
    let rowLength = dataSource.FieldCount
    let rowData = Array.zeroCreate(rowLength)

    for i = 0 to dataSource.FieldCount-1 do 
        rowData.SetValue(dataSource.GetValue(i),i)

    tableData <- rowData :: tableData

tableData |> List.toArray
```

This returns all the values in the table

Answer (score 0):

This is one way (using the [SqlClient type provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/index.html)) to select all data from a table. If your table is too large it will return a lot. So I just select the Top 1000 rows. Replace tablenn with your choice of table name. You can parametrize the columns, but if you need to put the table name itself as a parameter you might need to use a Stored Procedure that takes a Table as a parameter (or use quotations in other type providers).

However, this is a string so it's very easy to build it. Then again, it has to be a literal.

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.SqlClient.1.8.2\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.SqlClient.dll"

open FSharp.Data
open System

[<Literal>]
let connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\userName\Documents\Test.sdf.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=10"

[<Literal>]
let tblnn = "MyBigTable"

[<Literal>]
let qry = "SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM " + tblnn

let cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<qry, connectionString>(connectionString)
cmd.Execute() |> Seq.toArray
```

You can also use the stock [SqlDataConnection type provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/accessing-a-sql-database). It also makes it easy to select all data from a table.

Comment: That would work, but due to the structure of my program it won't allow me to use Literals and when I remove the literal I get this error again: "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."

Comment: unfortunately i'm not privvy to the structure of your program but If I understand you correctly you want the tablename to be a parameter?